# Mencoder codec - wmavds32.ax

Tags: linux, centos, video

I am setting up mencoder on CentOS and I have the following error:

[flv @ 0x86751c8]Unsupported video codec (7)
IMediaObject ERROR: 0x8724f4c  input format not accepted (0x80040205 : -2147220987)
Win32 LoadLibrary failed to load: wmavds32.ax, /usr/local/lib/codecs/wmavds32.ax, /usr/lib/win32/wmavds32.ax, /usr/local/lib/win32/wmavds32.ax
Warning: DS_Filter() could not open DirectShow DLL.  (DLL=wmavds32.ax)

I am going through codecs on http://www3.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/codecs/ and none seem to contain wmavds32.ax

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codecs are available on http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html underneath the Binary Codec Packages section.  It contains wmavds32.ax per http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/codecs-status.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I downloaded several codec packages from that page and none of them contained wmavds32.ax 

It appears that Windows Media Audio 9 Speech DShow is missing.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Win32codecs-essential pack for your architecture?  It should contain the files which are needed.

You could also try downloading the source for the w32codec-all and extract it to /usr/lib/win32, after that create symlinks to it in /usr/lib/codecs and /usr/local/codecs.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but they do not contain wmavds32.ax.
I tired 
win32codecs-20040703.tar.bz2.tar
win32codecs-essential-20040703.tar.bz2.tar
windows-all-20071007.zip
all-20071007.tar.bz2.tar
essential-20071007.tar.bz2.tar
None of the packages have wmavds32.ax

How could mplayer say that that codec is supported but not have it in the packages?

Answer (score 0):

I updated mencoder to the latest version (via SVN) and do not receive this error. Duh..